# Which UI Design is better for iPhone?

Tags: cocoa-touch, user-interface, human-computer-interface

I have a PickerView for choosing time. For example, the user can choose 5 hours and 10 minutes. I should use one picker view to display two row... or I should separate to two picker view, in the middle, I use a label "hour", and "minute". Which UI design is better? and why? thx you.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd use an [`UIDatePicker`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html), as described by the HIG [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ApplicationControls/ApplicationControls.html). It's the standard way to do this, and would mean users familiar with other applications will instantly be familiar with the control of yours. It contains labels on the spin-wheels so avoids your problem of making it clear to the user what each control represents.